# Error: RuntimeException and Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I tried to make log out function. but after run the code. I got these errors.

before this code I test the login function it works without error.
and saved Authentication to the Firebase

---

The Error was Solved!

The Solution is change the version of firebase-database from 19.2.0 -> 19.6.0

---

My Errors are

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fbapp/com.example.fbapp.MainActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:97)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:57)
```

I think here is the problem

> ```
>         ***at com.example.fbapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)***
> ```

```
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

And these are my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fbapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
 
import com.example.fbapp.Model.Users;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Firebase
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

The one of the Error is here the 33 lines

> ```
> myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
> ```

```
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
             }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    //Adding Logout Functionality

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fbapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'



}
```

Comment: Did you added `json` file in your android folder ?

Comment: @Ashish Yes of course I did!

Comment: Please try to upgrade the version cause there is more solution which says upgrade version

Comment: @Ashush Android Studio? I am using 4.1.1

Comment: I am asking for upgrade realtime database version to latest one to `19.6.0`

Comment: @Ashush OMG it works! thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Post it as answer in your question.